# How to troubleshoot MySQL Syntax ERROR 1064?

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error

Context

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Attempt to create data base object per https://github.com/curzon01/mqtt2sql

```
mysql --host localhost -u root -p < mysql.sql
```

Symptom

```
user@mysql:~/mqtt2sql$ mysql --host localhost -u root -p < mysql.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 94: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS `mqtt_history_view` AS
SELECT
    h.id,
    h.ts AS 'ts',
    m.ts' at line 1
```

`mysql.sql` excerpt

A complete listing of the sql script is found here:
https://github.com/curzon01/mqtt2sql/blob/master/mysql.sql

The error message indicates line 94 of the sql script:
[image]

A forked version of the .sql script returned the same result.

## Question

What is the next step to diagnose / troubleshoot the error?  Hopefully, the syntax error it is obvious to the experienced eye.  Thank you

Comment: [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) has `IF NOT EXISTS`, but [CREATE VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) does not. (You probably want `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`.)

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @ceejayoz or the script was meant for mariadb and not mysql...

Comment: You do what it says in the message. Check the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer your exact question:

> What is the next step to diagnose / troubleshoot the error?

Look at the context given in the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 94: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS `mqtt_history_view` AS

The error tells you exactly where the parser got confused. It found some words starting with `IF NOT EXISTS...` and was not expecting those words. That's where your SQL was wrong.

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS ...
ok ok...    ^ error starts here
```

Your next step is to look up the reference documentation for the CREATE VIEW statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

```
CREATE
    [OR REPLACE]
    [ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
    [DEFINER = user]
    [SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]
    VIEW view_name [(column_list)]
```

There are some parts of the syntax that are optional, indicated by square brackets. But notice that `IF NOT EXISTS` does not appear in any part of this syntax. It is not recognized by MySQL's SQL parser.

You can use `CREATE OR REPLACE...` which probably accomplishes what you want.

**Pro tip:** Keep the reference documentation handy. Use it as often as you need. I've been using MySQL since 2001, and I look still things up in the documentation several times per day, whenever I am in doubt of some specific syntax or feature that I don't use often enough to have it memorized.

Comment: Thank you for 'walking' me through the line of thinking. Excellent communication.   I removed `IF NOT EXISTS` and executed the script without error.   If the script executes again, then it will execute `CREATE VIEW` unconditionally, which leaves me to wonder why and any consequences.  Looking forward to any insights

Comment: My insight, and it hardly counts as insight, is that you could try it to find out the consequences. Then you could read the manual page I linked to to learn more.